# Dynamic sizing in ActionScript (drawRect)?

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, resize, drawing, drawrect

We can create a rectangle at (0,0) and height and width of 40 with `mySprite.graphics.drawRect(0,0,40,40);`. However, suppose it is necessary to create a rectangle that fills exactly half the screen (this is for mobile devices, so screen size will vary). How can we accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to get the size of the screen, you can use this :

```
var w = stage.stageWidth;
var h = stage.stageHeight;
```

Then you can simply draw your rect using theses variables

```
mySprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, w / 2, h / 2);
```

Comment: However, we would want to keep either the width or the height full size to make a half screen, if I am correct. Dividing both by two creates a quarter size rectangle, no?

Comment: Yes, if you divide both by two, you'll have (talking about surface), 1/4 of the total screen's surface. You'll have to be more clever about calculation to have what you want. But it's another problem :) If you know the percent, just apply it.